Biblatex -- reverse the order of a string and argument in an LBX language file
I have written a small Biblatex LBX file for Vietnamese to take care of just a few strings to denote pages and backref citations. It is literally:
\ProvidesFile{vietnamese.lbx}
[\abx@lbxid]

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  page             = {{trang}{tr\adddotspace}},
  pages            = {{trang}{tr\adddotspace}},
  urlfrom          = {{Khai thác từ }{Khai thác từ }},
  urlseen          = {{Khai thác từ }{Khai thác từ }},
  backrefpage      = {{trích dẫn ở trang}{trích dẫn ở tr\adddotspace}},
  backrefpages     = {{trích dẫn ở trang}{trích dẫn ở tr\adddotspace}},
}
\endinput

which takes care of this limited job well.
I would like now to add the string for translator which in Vietnamese is dịch but it is written AFTER the name as in:
Phạm Thị Ly dịch

to mean
Translated by Pham Thi Ly

How does one reverse the order of "string" and "argument" using an LBX file?
The same thing will be usefull to, for example, Chinese, where a page-number or the total-numbers of pages is reported BEFORE the string as in:
15頁

356頁數


For the Vietnamese translator string, try something like this.
\renewbibmacro*{bytranslator+others}{%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}%
                and
                test {\iflanguage{vietnamese}}}%
        {\printnames{translator}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \bibstring{bytranslator}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
            \clearname{translator}}{}%
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}%
                and
                not test {\iflanguage{vietnamese}}}%
        {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \printnames{translator}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
            \clearname{translator}}{}}

I'm not sure it's the prettiest change, but it works, within your parameters.
For the Chinese page string, try this.
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}
    {\iflanguage{chinese}%
        {{#1}%
        \printtext{\bibstring{pages}}}%
        {\printtext{\bibstring{pages}}%
        \addspace#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}
    {\iflanguage{chinese}%
        {{#1}%
        \printtext{\bibstring{page}}}%
        {\printtext{\bibstring{page}}%
        \addspace#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagetotal}
    {\iflanguage{chinese}%
        {{#1}%
        \printtext{\bibstring{page}}}%
        {\printtext{\bibstring{page}}%
        \addspace#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}
    {\iflanguage{chinese}%
        {#1%
        \ifnumerals{#1}%
            {\ifnumeral{#1}{\pno}{\ppno}}%
            {}}%
        {\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}}

Sorry, but I couldn't find a better way to custom the postnote field.
Don't forget to make both vietnamese.lbx and chinese.lbx files: I think the package hasn't got a Chinese translation too.

Note that these definitions would have to live in the .lbx files (more specifically, the bibliography extras) and couldn't be applied globally, since that would change the output for other languages in a multi-language document. Having these definitions in the .lbx overrides style choices, though, or may be incompatible with them. So this is tricky. The OP also asked about this at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1374, where I pointed to how things are done in magyar.lbx for Hungarian.
